# Return the SUM of column in JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with a number of joins, I want to return the sum of a column from the **JOIN reviews** results... any ideas?

```
SELECT *,user.id AS u_id
FROM user_connects
    JOIN user ON user_connects.user_y = user.id
    JOIN reviews ON user_connects.user_y = reviews.user
 WHERE user_connects.user_x = 1
 LIMIT 25
```

What I want to return something like this, with [1] index **totalcolumls** being the SUM result of the reviews table:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["user_x"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["user_y"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["date_created"]=>
    string(10) "1457593440"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Donald"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Trump"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "68"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["img_url"]=>
    string(10) "donald.jpg"
    ["keto_score"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["date_created_dt"]=>
    string(19) "2016-03-09 07:00:00"
    ["u_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  },
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (12) {
    ["totalcolumls"]=>
    string(1) "2"
   }
}
```

Comment: Limit, but no order by... Are you sure about that?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, combined with `SUM()`.

Comment: Any examples with the GROUP BY relevant to the above

Comment: Nice dummy data :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
SELECT count(reviews.*) AS total_review_column, user_connects.*, reviews.*, user.*, user.id AS u_id
FROM user_connects
    JOIN user ON user_connects.user_y = user.id
    JOIN reviews ON user_connects.user_y = reviews.user
 WHERE user_connects.user_x = 1
 group by reviews.user
```